# Get the extra values from the query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am just learning SQL. I am in a confused state on how to get the below result:

```
select count(*) 
from TABLE_NAME 
where column1 like '%mystring%' and column2 = 'mystring';
```

Output:

```
120
```

If I do :

```
select count(*) 
from TABLE_NAME 
where column1 like '%mystring%'
```

I am getting the result : `122`

How do I get the two extra results which are coming when running the second query?

I learned basics in w3schools and having issues while implementing it. Any help is appreciated here :)

Comment: eg:   'xmystring'  is valid for the firsts query  but not for the second

Comment: Your first query has two filters, the second only has one filter. What exactly are you trying to see - the actual two records that a missing, i.e. all their column values? Or just the number 2? (Hint: you can negate equality with `!=`. Though you may have to think about how nulls are handled.)

Comment: Venn diagram. The second condition is less restrictive: clearly there are two rows where the condition matches on `column1` while `column2` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 records that have column1 like '%mystring%' and don't have column2='mystring'.
In the first query these records are filtered out, and in the second they're not.
If you want to find out what these records are to help you understand, run the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE column1 LIKE '%mystring%'
AND column2 != 'mystring'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will bring 2 "missing" records:

```
select count(*) from TABLE_NAME where column1 like '%mystring%' and  nvl(column2,'-')<>'mystring';
```

In these 2 records `column2` is either not equal to `'mystring'` or is `null`.

Here I use `nvl` in order to handle possible null values ([nvl function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php)).

Another approach would be

```
select count(*) from TABLE_NAME where column1 like '%mystring%' and  (column2<>'mystring' or column2 is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be summarized like :

```
with t as
(
 select 'abmystringcd' column1, 'abmystringcd' column2 from dual union all
 select 'abmystringcd' column1, 'mystring'     column2 from dual union all
 select 'abmystringcd' column1, 'mystring'     column2 from dual union all
 select 'abmystringcd' column1, 'mystring'     column2 from dual union all
 select 'abmystringcd' column1, 'mystring'     column2 from dual union all
 select 'abmystringcd' column1, 'mystring'     column2 from dual
)  
  select count(1) cnt from t where column1 like '%mystring%' union all
  select count(1) cnt from t where column2   =   'mystring';

 CNT
 ----
  6  -- [ # of strings including "mystring" ]
  5  -- [ # of exact matches for "mystring" ]
```